# Porting an Alexa Skill - completing or continuing the dialog

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, bixby

I have a skill in Alexa, Cortana and Google and in each case, there is a concept of terminating the flow after speaking the result or keeping the mic open to continue the flow. The skill is mostly in an Http API call that returns the information to speak, display and a flag to continue the conversation or not.

In Alexa, the flag returned from the API call and passed to Alexa is called **shouldEndSession**. In Google Assistant, the flag is **expect_user_response**.

So in my code folder, the API is called from the Javascript file and returns a JSON object containing three elements: **speech** (the text to speak - possibly SSML); **displayText** (the text to display to the user); and **shouldEndSession** (true or false).

The action calls the JavaScript code with type Search and a collect segment. It then outputs the JSON object mentioned above. This all works fine except I don't know how to handle the shouldEndSession. Is this done in the action perhaps with the validate segment?

For example, *"Hi Bixby, ask car repair about changing my tires"* would respond with the answer and be done. But something like *"Hi Bixby, ask car repair about replacing my alternator"*. In this case, the response may be *"I need to know what model car you have. What model car?"*. The user would then say *"Toyota"* and then Bixby would complete the dialog with the answer or maybe ask for more info.

I'd appreciate some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: The Bixby model of developing a voice assistant is very different from how Alexa works. I would encourage you to review the sample capsules to get a feel for it.

To answer your specific question, from the information you have provided, I see a `structure` called `Car` that has parts (alternator, tires), the year, the model name, the make ... and whatever else is required to support the UX ... Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it can easily be done in Bixby by input prompt when a required input is missing. You can build input-view to better enhance the user experience.

To start building the capsule, I would suggest the following:

1. Learn more about Bixby on https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide
2. Try some sample capsules and watch some tutorial videos on https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules
3. If you have a Bixby enabled Samsung device, check our marketplace for ideas and inspirations.

Comment: My understanding is that if an input is required and missing, the API won't even be called. In my case, it is after return of the API that I need to control the flow based on the property returned. Above, I mentioned that the validate section may hold the answer but that was wrong - validate is before the API call similar to what you said about the missing required input. I now think the Action output section is where I need to have an IF statement or something to reference the returned structure.